# Как удалить символ из консоли? python

Tags: python

Всем привет!
Я хочу сделать так, чтобы символ в консоли(в выводе) `\` менялся на  `/`, и после этого к  `-` и так далее. Как это сделать?
Вот код:

```py
print("Загрузка /",end = "")
while True:
    #удалить последний символ
    print("-",end="")
    #удалить последний символ
    print("\",end="")
    #удалить последний символ
    print("/",end="")
```

Comment: '\r' в начале строки и потом новый символ

Comment: `\b` - отступить на символ назад в той же строке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверное поздно, но может кому пригодится.
Существует классная библиотека `halo` и пак дополнений `spinners`

```
pip install spinners halo
```

Пример работы:

```py
from spinners import Spinners
from halo import Halo 
import time
spinner = Halo(text='loading', spinner=Spinners.dqpb.value) 
spinner.start() 

time.sleep(15)

spinner.stop()
```

В параметр `spinner` можно передавать уже готовые словари и модуля `Spinners`
Со всем списком анимаций можно ознакомиться [тут](https://github.com/manrajgrover/py-spinners) на странице библиотеки

Comment: Прикольно. Хотя в google colab как-то криво работает, даже если взять HaloNotebook

Answer (score 1):

У меня получилось примерно так:

```py
word = "Загрузка"
import time
print("/ " + word, end="")
while True:
    time.sleep(0.3)
    print("\r- " + word, end="")
    time.sleep(0.3)
    print("\r\\ " + word, end="")
    time.sleep(0.3)
    print("\r/ " + word, end="")
```